# Narrow down type based on class property (from .filter, .find, etc.)

Tags: typescript

I want to narrow down type based on the class property when calling array `.filter` or `.find`

```js
class Square {
    type: "square";

    constructor() {
        this.type = "square";
    }
}

class Circle {
    type: "circle";

    constructor() {
        this.type = "circle";
    }
}

const objects = [
    new Circle(),
    new Square(),
    new Circle(),
    new Square(),
];

// I want `circles` to be Circle[], not (Circle | Square)[]
const circles = objects.filter(o => o.type === "circle");

// I want `square` to be Square | undefined, not Circle | Square | undefined
const square = objects.find(o => o.type === "square");
```

Is this possible in TypeScript?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCOBXMAnAptA3gKGn6ALgJ4AOaAXNAEQRKppUDc2u+wA9gHYQEqLAF2KABQBKLK3z4CACwCWEAHTEy0ALzVaydE0nQAvtkPZQkGAGE5KUBhxSVFasCs3dejt179BI8XanS8koO6k4uIAzMUobGHjzQ7ABGAFZoAjAaANp6nGgA7tCW1hFiADQ5+XB06GUVBUU2tVK5BQjaaLUAuszYAPS90ACS0HlgnATQzsVoMILQiRgNEZmdJlzxUzYZCSlpBEoAZnIgBGgi7OoAfAnKpBhqD2HTVKI9-UMjYxNa9IQXC1V2tAAD7QRCcAAmaCOuQha080B+6FCSVS6UUMIhwguamu7FuqgeGho1QYryAA)

Comment: Which ES-version do you have to use? any restrictions or would ES2019 work? (I ask because the playground is set to ES2017).

Comment: `objects.filter((o): o is Circle => o.type === "circle");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [*type guard* functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). Here's an example with the type guard functions defined ahead of time:

```typescript
function isSquare(obj: {type: string}): obj is Square {
    return obj.type === "square";
}

function isCircle(obj: {type: string}): obj is Circle {
    return obj.type === "circle";
}

// ...

// I want circles to be Circle[]
const circles = objects.filter(isCircle);

// I want square to be Square | undefined
const square = objects.find(isSquare);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCOBXMAnAptA3gKGn66YAJgPYB2IAntAC6UAOaAXNAEQRKpqsDc2u+YOQg0UiYDRIoAFAEosA-PhoALAJYQAdHUbQAvGw7J0vRdAC+2SwDNEZCWvLQNCY2mkkARgCsWmHczQIihqZADm5rIsXt7OMK5cCkroNIgoZNAx2gwYenmGnCZ8ltigkDAAwmoooBg4yWjE5FS0OSyswNW1pmZCZMHikjLy9UrK6loB+mydNSDcfEqWNnYOThpVc+4xfgEswaERUZk+cdCbtUn4KWkZWVN5Bh1d86YlfSIn3mgSMAYA2mYyGgAO7nF7uWQAGiBoLghUhMKUwLBF3mciR+BR8LcGOwAF0+NgAPTE6AASWgILAZBo0FmtRgkmgngwaLQ-3xpWEdIZ8z+Xx+NC01jUIBoaBkGwhsiJpIpVJpdKMiWZrJxiQAPtA7EQ0KLgURuf1lQjpjEhSLQkRpC4EbKgA)

...but they can also be inline:

```typescript
// I want circles to be Circle[]
const circles = objects.filter((obj): obj is Circle => obj.type === "circle");

// I want square to be Square | undefined
const square = objects.find((obj): obj is Square => obj.type === "square");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCOBXMAnAptA3gKGn66YAJgPYB2IAntAC6UAOaAXNAEQRKpqsDc2u+YOQg0UiYDRIoAFAEosA-PhoALAJYQAdHUbQAvGw7J0vRdAC+2SwDNEZCWvLQNCY2mkkARgCsWmHczQIihqZADm5rIsXt7OMK5cCkpW-KCQMADCaiigGDhKhKQU1AEsrMDZuaZmQmTB4pIy8vlKyupaAfpsFTkg3HxKljZ2Dk4aWb3uMX6lQaKhEVHQMXHQE7lJ+Og0iChkyz7aDBh6p92VfaaW2LUiB95oEjAGANpmZGgA7msX7rIANO8vnBOOg5IClB9vus+uCgd8EmCAdgALp8bAAegx0AAktBPmAyDRoD1cjBJNBPBgYWgXiibsJiaS+s97o8aFprGoQDQ0DIPD4lisND9JvoAHz3I66U4Gcq-ViydFY3H4wnEoyJClUkFuaAAH2gdiIaC5HyIDLqGtBJzZT00ZqI0gF3iFPlWiJOkpi0pOZ3YNsVfCAA)

Comment: This works, thank you. So there's no way for typescript to automatically detects the type based on the property value? Since the type of `type` property is a static string (not `string`) I thought Typescript would be able to detect it automatically.

Comment: @Owl - I was slightly surprised that making `type` `readonly` didn't make it infer correctly, but there are limits on what the TypeScript compiler does because of how long it would take to do it (not just whether it *could* do it). Still, I was surprised. I can't say for sure there isn't another way (TypeScript is hugely complicated), but type guard functions work. :-)