# Union type in array - how to set/change value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build an array with two possible value types:

```
type Loading = {
    loading: true
}

type Loaded = {
    loading: false,
    date: string,
    value: number,
}

type Items = Loading | Loaded

const items: Items[] = []
```

so far so good, but now I try to pick value by `.find` method:

```
const firstLoaded = items.find(({ loading }) => !loading)
```

and `firstLoaded` should be a type of `Loaded|undefined` - how to make TS know that type?

```
console.log(firstLoaded?.date) // doesnt work
```

and 2nd question: how to change value from Loading to Loaded in array:

```
const firstUnloaded = items.find(({ loading }) => loading) 
firstUnloaded.loading = false // doesnt work
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gQwCYEsB2BzKBeKBvAKCmKgBtFVMAuKYAJwFcICBfAg0SWCiJHfIiXLJ0GGgDMEpAM4QANIOJIEwCDWn1RCklABuUpjTQMAtgCMIdBWw7hoASVUnp-eCMxQAPt2S92AYzg0DSgUJ2kaRwhnAG0AXX549gB6ZMkAa2hlYAQCMOjpADowBmkACwAKAkIdYUoxWkZoYlY5KGrFMgpRGnomVvaaoW7qKEkZeU7stSgAcgBGAAYAWiXlgCZFzdntEn1SQyh51gBKAKCQ8RQ6DTckXn5850KrtCQKirwu9ywWE5wAHxQACEdVE-wIgWCcFIEEK5AwFSuN2Ad14AH5CtN-qkoGU4AB3WhwKAYCDAKCBOh0CD+CmcCDo87BCnIjQAVTQdQeuCeRVe70+33qUD+gOF4PabOAnO5SHhIywuHGsiguPxROAJP8ZQQmGgDOJwoeer4sgp2QQ6KAA)

Comment: You have to tell TS your function is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) so it can narrow the result - `items.find((item): item is Loaded => !item.loading)` https://tsplay.dev/wjaZvW

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Narrow down type based on class property (from .filter, .find, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279417/typescript-narrow-down-type-based-on-class-property-from-filter-find-etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, this might be a good use case for [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isLoaded(item: Items): item is Loaded {
  return (item as Loaded).loading === false;
}

if (isLoaded(item)) {
   console.log(firstLoaded.date) // Should work
}
```

For the second one, I think you can't just convert it like that. Instead you need to replace array element with another element, for example by assigning it directly like `items[index] = convertToLoaded(items[index])`

Comment: For the 2nd question I've tried:


`const newItem: Loaded = { loaded: true, data: 'xxx', value: 1 }
Object.assign(oldIndexItem, Loaded)`


Is this also the correct way? Are there any downsides?

Comment: Note that Object.assign doesn't actually replace original item, but instead merges it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), so it might have some unintended side effects if you, for example, add more properties into the `Loading` type later.

Comment: Indeed yes, but in my case it won't, thank for help :)